# Transforming tables into xml

Tags: html, xml, xslt, html-table

I am interested in transforming a simple table into a set of xml elements. The table starts with two rows that are simple name-values for properties, but then it has embedded properties for a set of tests. I would like each test to be an XML element with a set of properties. I'm sure there is a straightforward approach to this, but I am having difficulty conceiving of the right approach.
Input is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Property Heading</td>
        <td>Value Heading</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Property1</td>
        <td>Value 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Property2</td>
        <td>Value 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test1</td>
        <td>Property t1.1</td>
        <td>Value t1.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td/>
        <td>Property t1.2</td>
        <td>Value t1.2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td/>
        <td>Property t1.3</td>
        <td>Value t1.3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test2</td>
        <td>Property t2.1</td>
        <td>Value t2.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td/>
        <td>Property t2.2</td>
        <td>Value t2.2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and desired output is

```
<table>
    <Property1>Value 1</Property1>
    <Property2>Value 2</Property2>
    <test>
        <Property_t1.1>Value t1.1</Property_t1.1>
        <Property_t1.2>Value t1.2</Property_t1.2>
        <Property_t1.3>Value t1.3</Property_t1.3>
    </test>
    <test>
        <Property_t2.1>Value t2.1</Property_t2.1>
        <Property_t2.2>Value t2.2</Property_t2.2>
    </test>
</table>
```

I have tried several approaches, but none work very well. I am hoping for a solution or a pointer in the right direction.

Comment: It's difficult to deduce the logic from the example. Please explain the rules in words.

Comment: We have a table that describes a conformance class. Property 1 and property 2 are properties of the conformance class. There can be any number of properties. The conformance class also has some number of tests that also have some number of properties. Each test should also be a class on its own. In the real world example I am trying to extract these from a Word XML file into XML so that I can transform them into simple html displays.

Comment: Those are not *rules*. I cannot figure out what in your example is constant and what is just an example. Please describe how to arrive at the expected output *manually*, step-by-step. And why is Property t1.3/Value t1.3 excluded from the output?

Comment: @michael.hor257k - Rules

Comment: `1) start table element <table>  
2) for row2+  
3) If row has 2 col  
 a) make element <col1>col2</col1>  
4) If row has 3 col and contains(col1,’test’)  
 <test><col2>col3</col2>  
5) for subsequent rows that have 3 cols and empty col1  
 <col2>col3</col2>  
6) continue until row with 3 cols and col1 contains “Test”, then </test>, return to 4  
7) </table>`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/table">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:element name="{tr[2]/td[1]}">
        <xsl:value-of select="tr[2]/td[2]"/>
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:element name="{tr[3]/td[1]}">
        <xsl:value-of select="tr[3]/td[2]"/>
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="tr[position() > 3][td[1] != '']"/>

    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="tr">
    <test>
      <xsl:element name="{translate(td[2], ' ', '_')}">
        <xsl:value-of select="td[3]"/>
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::tr[td[1] = '' and preceding-sibling::tr[td[1] != ''][1] = current()]">
        <xsl:element name="{translate(td[2], ' ', '_')}">
          <xsl:value-of select="td[3]"/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>   
    </test>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This answer has some helpful ideas, but it looks very specific. Is there a way to generalize it?

Comment: You were looking for a "pointer to the right direction"- so why not try and maybe comeback with next question?